# Save for later reading

Tags: chrome-for-android, offline, stock-browser

Back before chrome became the default browser for Android, there used to be a stock Android browser called "Browser" (anyone who used a stock version of Android before 4.2 knows what I'm talking about) 
Anyhow, It had a feature that allows you to save a Web page for later reading but that browser no longer exists and that feature doesn’t seem to exist in chrome.

Does this mean that now I have to install a third party app (such a Pocket) to save articles for later reading??

Answer (score 1):

Might not be ideal, but you can save the webpage to a pdf which you can read anytime:

> Menu > Print > PDF > Save

Now you can read your articles anytime, if you have a PDF reader installed.
The problem with this off course is that the page won't open in Chrome and that the way the page is displayed could depend on your choice of PDF reader. I use Adobe Reader, and it keeps any links intact.